# Wrong sign anticommutation relation for the Dirac field?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, fermions, dirac-equation, grassmann-numbers, anticommutator

Consider the Dirac Lagrangian $$\mathcal{L}=\psi ^{\dagger }\gamma ^{0}\left( 
\mathrm{i}\gamma ^{\rho }\partial _{\rho }-m\right) \psi .$$ The conjugate
momenta to $\psi ^{a}$ are defined, as usual, by $$\pi _{a}=\partial \mathcal{%
L}/\partial \dot{\psi}^{a}.$$ All references I have consulted claims that
this implies that $\pi _{a}=\mathrm{i}\psi _{a}^{\dagger }$, which seems
quite obvious. But why not $$\pi _{a}=-\mathrm{i}\psi _{a}^{\dagger }$$ in
view of fermion anticommutation, the minus sign arising from having to pass $%
\partial /\partial \dot{\psi}^{a}$ through $\psi ^{\dagger }$? Using such a
minus sign, though, leads of course to a nonsensical minus sign in the
anticommutation relation, $$\left\{ \psi ^{a}\left( \mathbf{x}\right) ,\psi
_{b}^{\dagger }\left( \mathbf{y}\right) \right\} ~=~-\delta _{b}^{a}\delta
^{\left( 3\right) }\left( \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\right) .$$ What am I missing?

**Update:** Following [the note 'Dirac Brackets' by Steven Avery](http://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imsc.res.in%2F~savery%2Fnotes%2Fdirac-brackets.pdf&ei=bEVsVbTiOeqrygPl-4GQDQ&usg=AFQjCNG_OgmUAImwEjQ6WAO32O3dKrKV7w&bvm=bv.94455598,d.bGQ&cad=rja),
define the following Poisson bracket (note the exact order of $\pi _{a}$ and $\psi ^{a}$):
$$
\left\{ f,g\right\} _{\text{P.B.}}=\int d^{3}x\left[ -\frac{\delta f}{\delta
\pi _{a}\left( \mathbf{x}\right) }\frac{\delta g}{\delta \psi ^{a}\left( 
\mathbf{x}\right) }+\left( -1\right) ^{\varepsilon _{f}\varepsilon _{g}}%
\frac{\delta g}{\delta \pi _{a}\left( \mathbf{x}\right) }\frac{\delta f}{%
\delta \psi ^{a}\left( \mathbf{x}\right) }\right] ,
$$
where $\varepsilon _{f}$ and $\varepsilon _{g}$ are the Grassmann parities
of $f$ and $g$, respectively. For Grassmann-even $f$ and $g$, this bracket
correctly reduces to the usual Poisson bracket. For the 'classical' Dirac
Lagrangian, formulated in terms of Grassmann-odd $\psi^{a}$ and $\pi_{a}$, it becomes
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\{ \psi ^{a}\left( \mathbf{x}\right) ,\pi _{b}\left( \mathbf{y}\right)
\right\} _{\text{P.B.}} &=&-\int d^{3}z\left[ \frac{\delta \psi ^{a}\left( 
\mathbf{x}\right) }{\delta \pi _{c}\left( \mathbf{z}\right) }\frac{\delta
\pi _{b}\left( \mathbf{y}\right) }{\delta \psi ^{c}\left( \mathbf{z}\right) }
+\frac{\delta \pi _{b}\left( \mathbf{y}\right) }{\delta \pi _{c}\left( 
\mathbf{z}\right) }\frac{\delta \psi ^{a}\left( \mathbf{x}\right) }{\delta
\psi ^{c}\left( \mathbf{z}\right) }\right]  \\
&=&-\int d^{3}z\left[ 0+\delta _{b}^{c}\delta ^{\left( 3\right) }\left( 
\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{z}\right) \delta _{c}^{a}\delta ^{\left( 3\right) }\left( 
\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{z}\right) \right]  \\
&=&-\delta _{b}^{a}\delta ^{\left( 3\right) }\left( \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}
\right) .
\end{eqnarray*}
If $\pi _{a}=-\mathrm{i}\psi _{a}^{\dagger }$, note minus sign, then
$$
\left\{ \psi ^{a}\left( \mathbf{x}\right) ,\psi_{b}^{\dagger}\left( \mathbf{y}\right)
\right\} _{\text{P.B.}}=-\mathrm{i}\delta _{b}^{a}\delta ^{\left( 3\right)
}\left( \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\right) ,
$$
which using the 'quantum bracket = $\mathrm{i} \times$ Poisson bracket'-rule
yields the correct quantum anticommutation relation:
$$
\left\{ \psi ^{a}\left( \mathbf{x}\right) ,\psi_{b}^{\dagger}\left( \mathbf{y}\right)
\right\} =\delta _{b}^{a}\delta ^{\left( 3\right) }\left( \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{%
y}\right) .
$$

Comment: What do you mean "why not" - what is the actual result of calculating $\partial\mathcal{L}/\partial \dot{\psi}$?

Comment: The "why not" is meant rhetorically, as I think there should be a minus sign coming from, as I write, passing the variational derivative through from the left to right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OP asks about the Legendre transformation from the Lagrangian to the Hamiltonian formulation of fermions. This question has already been asked and answered in e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43502/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175928/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57964/2451) Phys.SE posts.

Let us here just list a number of subtle points in this important and interesting calculation:

1. More generally, let $\phi^{\alpha}$ denote a field of Grassmann-parity $\varepsilon_{\alpha}$. When defining Grassmann-odd canonical momentum, should we use derivatives
   $$ \pi^R_{\alpha}~:=~\frac{\partial_R {\cal L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}^{\alpha}}~=~(-1)^{\varepsilon_{\alpha}}\frac{\partial_L {\cal L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}^{\alpha}}~=:~(-1)^{\varepsilon_{\alpha}}\pi^L_{\alpha}\tag{1}$$
   that act from the right or from the left? Short answer: It should be correlated with choice of kinetic term
   $${\cal L}_H~=~\pi^R_{\alpha}\dot{\phi}^{\alpha}-{\cal H}~=~\dot{\phi}^{\alpha}\pi^L_{\alpha}-{\cal H}\tag{2} $$
   in the Hamiltonian Lagrangian density ${\cal L}_H$. This seems to resolves OP's question about sign conventions.$^1$
2. Be careful to use a consistent sign convention for the Poisson bracket$^2$ (PB)
   $$\{F,G\}_{PB}~=~\int d^3x\left( \frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \phi^{\alpha}({\bf x})} \frac{\delta_L G}{\delta \pi^R_{\alpha}({\bf x})}-\frac{\delta_R F}{\delta \pi^L_{\alpha}({\bf x})} \frac{\delta_L G}{\delta \phi^{\alpha}({\bf x})}\right) $$
   $$~=~-(-1)^{\varepsilon_F\varepsilon_G}\{G,F\}_{PB}.
    \tag{3}$$
   The fundamental PBs read
   $$ \{\phi^{\alpha}({\bf x}), \pi^R_{\beta}({\bf x}^{\prime})\}_{PB}
   ~=~\delta^{\alpha}_{\beta}~\delta^3({\bf x}-{\bf x}^{\prime})
   ~=~-\{\pi^L_{\beta}({\bf x}),\phi^{\alpha}({\bf x}^{\prime})\}_{PB} ,\tag{4}$$
   and the rest are zero.
   Note that the above PB (3) is consistent with super-canonical transformations, and satisfies super-skew/anti-symmetry, a super-Jacobi identity
   $$\sum_{\text{cycl. }F,G,H} (-1)^{\varepsilon_F\varepsilon_H}\{\{F,G\}_{PB},H\}_{PB}~=~0, \tag{5}$$
   and a [super-Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_superalgebra).
   So does the [super-commutator](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/graded+commutator)
   $$ [\hat{F}, \hat{G}\} 
   ~:=~\hat{F}\hat{G}-(-1)^{\varepsilon_F\varepsilon_G}\hat{G}\hat{F}
   ~\longleftrightarrow~i\hbar\{F,G\}_{PB} +{\cal O}(\hbar^2) ,\tag{6}$$
   which is consistent with the correspondence principle.
3. In the fermionic case, be careful not to confuse the classical PB $\{\cdot,\cdot\}_{PB}$ and the quantum anti-commutator $\{\cdot,\cdot\}_+$.
4. Going back to OP's example, can we treat $\psi$ and $\psi^{\dagger}$ as independent variables? If so, is the momentum for $\psi^{\dagger}$ zero?
5. Is the Legendre transformation singular? Are there constraints?

The answers to the last points 4 and 5 are given in the linked Phys.SE posts.

--

$^1$ Conventionally, one uses $\pi^R_{\alpha}$ rather than $\pi^L_{\alpha}$, cf. e.g. a comment between eqs. (44.6) and (44.7) in Srednicki's QFT book. A prepublication draft PDF file is available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html).

$^2$ Here we are ignoring a discussion of the existence of functional derivatives, which rely on a consistent choice of boundary conditions, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134619/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: Earlier today I checkmarked your answer. But later, after having discovered the material by Steven Avery, compare my Update above, I had second thoughts. It seems to me that acting from the right, as you suggest, is not necessary, at least not at the 'classical' level. But perhaps I am just messing together Poisson brackets and quantum brackets, or what seems to be equivalent, the 'classical' formalism and the quantum formalism. But my point is, I guess, that I would like the usual 'quantum bracket = i times Poisson bracket'-rule to be applicable in the fermionic/Grassmann-odd case as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Eq. (3) is particularly interesting to me. I will look more into the details in the days to come. I would have liked to give you a Vote Up point, but my low reputation score does not presently allow me to do so.