# Problem calculating the variation of this action

Tags: field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, action, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

If we take a Hamiltonian density to be as following

$$
\mathscr{H}=\frac{1}{2}\Pi^2+\frac{1}{2}\partial_i\varphi\partial_i\varphi+\frac{1}{2}m^2\varphi^2+\frac{1}{4}\lambda\varphi^4,
$$

and we have the following action

$$
\mathcal{S}=\int \mathrm{d}^{d+1}x(\Pi\dot\varphi-\mathscr{H}).
$$

How am I suppose to calculate

$$
\delta\mathcal{S}=\int\mathrm{d}^{d+1}x\frac{\delta\mathcal{S}[\varphi]}{\delta\varphi(x)}\delta\varphi(x)+\dots
$$

and

$$
\delta\mathcal{S}=\int\mathrm{d}^{d+1}x\frac{\delta\mathcal{S}[\Pi]}{\delta\Pi(x)}\delta\Pi(x)+\dots
$$

For example with $\varphi$:

$$
\frac{\delta\mathcal{S}[\varphi(x)]}{\delta\varphi(x)}=\int\mathrm{d}^{d+1}y\frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi(x)}(\Pi\dot\varphi+\mathscr{H}),
$$

which gives me

$$
\frac{\delta\mathcal{S}[\varphi(x)]}{\delta\varphi(x)}=\int\mathrm{d}^{d+1}y\left(\partial_0(\Pi\delta^{d+1}(x-y))-\dot\Pi\delta^{d+1}(x-y)-\frac{\delta\mathscr{H}}{\delta\varphi(x)}\right).
$$

I know I am supposed to get to the Hamilton's equations

$$\dot\Pi=-\frac{\delta\mathcal{H}}{\delta\varphi}$$

where $$\mathcal{H}=\int\mathrm{d}^{d}x\mathscr{H},$$ but it seems like it won't work.

Comment: You didn't calculate the functional derevatives correctly. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252467/2451

Answer (score 0):

I think I came up with a solution:
$$
\frac{\delta\mathcal{S}[\varphi]}{\delta\varphi(x)}={\frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi(x)}\int\mathrm{d}^{d+1}y\left(\Pi\dot\varphi-\mathscr{H}\right)\nonumber\\
=\frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi(x)}\int\mathrm{d}^{d+1}y\left(\Pi\dot\varphi\right)-\frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi(x)}\int\mathrm{d}^{d+1}y\mathscr{H}\nonumber\\
=-\frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi(x)}\int\mathrm{d}^{d+1}y\left(\Pi\dot\varphi\right)-\frac{\delta}{\delta\varphi(x)}\int\mathcal{H}\mathrm{d} t+\underbrace{\text{boundary terms}}_\textrm{=0}\nonumber\\
=-\int\mathrm{d}^{d+1}y\left(\dot\Pi\frac{\delta\varphi}{\delta\varphi(x)}\right)-\int\frac{\delta\mathcal{H}}{\delta\varphi(x)}\mathrm{d} t\nonumber\\
=-\int\mathrm{d}^{d+1}y\left(\dot\Pi\delta^{d}(x-y)\right)-\int\frac{\delta\mathcal{H}}{\delta\varphi(x)}\mathrm{d} t\nonumber\\
=\int\left(-\dot\Pi-\frac{\delta\mathcal{H}}{\delta\varphi(x)}\right)\mathrm{d} t\nonumber.}
$$
Since the variation of the action must vanish, it implies that
$$
-\dot\Pi-\frac{\delta\mathcal{H}}{\delta\varphi}=0 \implies \dot\Pi=-\frac{\delta\mathcal{H}}{\delta\varphi},
$$
as desired. We can do exactly the same for the $\Pi$ equation.