# A question about commutation relation and functional derivatives

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, commutator, functional-derivatives

In wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation. In quantum mechanics the Hamiltonian ${\hat {H}}$, (generalized) coordinate $ {\hat {Q}}$ and (generalized) momentum ${\hat {P}}$ are all linear operators.
Further, since the Hamiltonian operator depends on the (generalized) coordinate and momentum operators, it can be viewed as a functional, and we may write (using functional derivatives):
$$[{\hat {H}},{\hat {Q}}]=\frac{\delta \hat{H}}{\delta \hat{P}}\cdot[\hat{P},\hat{Q}]\tag{1}$$
$$[{\hat {H}},{\hat {P}}]=\frac{\delta \hat{H}}{\delta \hat{Q}}\cdot[\hat{Q},\hat{P}]\tag{2}$$

Why do these two equations hold?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with OP's mentioned formulas (1) & (2) on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation#Derivation_from_Hamiltonian_mechanics) (December 2021).

- For starters a [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) (well, any derivative) does not readily make sense for operators wrt. an operator. There are all kinds of operator ordering issues$^1$.

Let us therefore from now on interpret (1) & (2) classically, i.e. remove all operator hats, and replace the commutator with a [Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket).

- In the point mechanical case, the functional derivative  in eqs. (1) & (2) is just an ordinary partial derivative.
- In field theory, the canonical variables $Q^i(x)$ and $P_j(x)$ depends of a spatial coordinate $x$. The canonical [Poisson bracket](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134619/2451) then becomes
  $$\begin{align} \{Q^i(x),P_j(y)\} ~=~& \delta^i_j \delta^d(x\!-\!y), \cr \{Q^i(x),Q^j(y)\} ~=~&0, \cr \{P_i(x),P_j(y)\} ~=~&0.\end{align} $$
  The Hamiltonian
  $$H~=~\int_M\! d^dx ~{\cal H}(Q(x),P(x),\partial Q(x),\partial P(x),x)$$
  is then a local functional integrated over $x$-space.
  The dot in eqs. (1) & (2) presumably stands for a [DeWitt condensed notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeWitt_notation) with an implicit summation and integration over repeated discrete and continuous indices.

In both cases, eqs. (1) & (2) follows from definitions.

--

$^1$ A remedy is in principle to introduce symbols for the operators, and a symbol-operator ordering prescription, e.g. Weyl-ordering, Wick-ordering, etc.

Comment: The context around OP's quoted equations was really all important here. The article first assumes Heisenberg's equations dA/dt = i [H,A] then states equations (1,2) and concludes with [Q,P] = i. Any take on that?

Comment: I'm curious because I think I see how to derive the commutation relation starting from Heisenberg's equations when I know the Hamiltonian. But I'm not sure how far I can get when the Hamiltonian is unknown.

Comment: Hi @Tavin. Thanks for the feedback. Try first to check if the logic in the corresponding classical setting of Hamiltonian mechanics makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The commutation with a conjugate operator does the same thing as a functional derivative. Assume that
$$ [\hat{P}(x_1),\hat{Q}(x_2)] = \delta(x_2-x_1) ~~~ \text{and} ~~~ [\hat{P},\hat{P}] = [\hat{Q},\hat{Q}] = 0 . $$
Then
$$ [\hat{P}^n,\hat{Q}]\cdot F = n \hat{P}^{n-1}\cdot F , $$
where $F$ is some arbitrary function of $x$. On the other hand, for
$$ \frac{\delta\hat{P}(x_2)}{\delta \hat{P}(x_1)} = \delta(x_2-x_1) , $$
we have
$$ \frac{\delta \hat{P}^n}{\delta \hat{P}(x_1)} \cdot F = n \hat{P}^{n-1} \cdot F . $$

Then, assuming $\hat{H}$ is a bivariate polynomial in $\hat{P}$ and $\hat{Q}$, it follows that the right-hand sides and left-hand sides in the two equations would produce the same results.

Comment: I do not see good reasons to keep the name of functional derivative for something where there is no explicit functional at all.

Comment: I don't know whether all $\hat{H}$ are bivariate polynomial.

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, all Hamiltonians are such bivariate polynomials. Can you give any counterexamples?